# Where can I find correct documentation of old floppy drive formats?

Tags: datasheet, interface, hardware, magnetics, protocol

I have an old drum machine with an ancient proprietary 3.5" SONY floppy disk drive with no information on the device itself that I have seen. The performance is spotty and it's very picky about disks. The problem now is that it's seemingly impossible to find an authoritive answer on format or suitable replacements. So many companies made incompatible proprietary solutions, and of course they have all left the scene by now making future compatibility questionable.

It's a shame that it's possible to read ancient text from Egypt and Greece, while not possible to read a floppy from the 1980s. Does anyone know where I can start to get an answer to this?

Comment: This is also a problem with old CNC machine tools, many of which had floppy disks. They're worth a lot of money and have a useful life of decades. There have been some replacements made - you might get lucky googling around and find that the same part number Sony drive was used in both, and someone has an SSD replacement or whatever.

Comment: Chances are that the drive hardware is standard, but the firmware used to control the standard drive is proprietary. I believe Apple used drives that were able to control the spinning speed, but all other drive's I am aware of the hardware was pretty standard. Common for 3.5" disks: single/double-sided, 80 tracks. The rest is up to the operating system to decide ... you wouldn't be the first one to reverse engineer number of sectors; bytes/sector; ... If I really wanted, I would try to set up a microcontroller to control the floppy disk drive and pull data from it for further analysis on a PC.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I have tried a standard PC floppy drive, as well as another SONY drive from a sampler, but non of these worked unfortunately. There's one SD card reader with a dipswitch meant to solve all these problems that I have found, but I would like to leave it stock if possible, and I'm also curious to find out about it out of principle. :) http://lotharek.pl/product.php?pid=114

Comment: I have a friend who had a drum machine (brand escapes at present) AND I bought and quite a few single sided 5.25" floppy drives long long long ago. I may have one or two in my dungeon. Memory suggests they MAY have been Sony.  (I have one or two of all sorts of things there :-).) What model? What is the drum machine brand/model? - you MAY get lucky, but probably not.  | Interest only - where are you located?

Comment: Is it like [**this one**](http://www.recycledgoods.com/sony-oa-d31v-14-360k-400k-3-5-fdd-vintage.html)? Single sided but there is also a double sided version. This i/f was proprietary so you pretty much have to find an old inventory somewhere. You should add the FDD model number to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would check usenet comp.arch.fpga as there have been several projects aimed at making fpga boards that run a favorite old CPM, Tandy or Apple II machine. 
Another possibility is to use a piece of hardware to emulate a floppy assuming you can recreate the files stored on your disks. 
Look at http://www.thesvd.com/
If your piece of equipment uses both a disk I/O and file format like one of the supported pieces of hardware, this would save you a lot of trouble.
Jim Sather's book Understanding the Apple II+ gives a detailed description of both the circuitry used in the Apple's disk II controller (it was a state machine made of a 555 timer a small bipolar prom and a few TTL parts. There was a second prom for a boot loader)
There is also a great deal of explanation of the 6502 routines used for disk read write I/O.
Likely that information would only be minimally helpful as a starting point if you were forced to make a solution from scratch.
The early Apple Lisa and Macintosh machines used Sony 3.5 drives, so projects emulating those boards will likely work as a drive controller with the drive, even if the disk formatting is different.